# How Can I Install Another Desktop Environment In Debian?

Tags: debian, desktop-environment

I tried to install Unity, and the Lubuntu desktop environment, but all I got as the result was this:

```
> Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-desktop
```

or

```
> Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: `Unity` is Ubuntu-only. LXDE (lubuntu) can be installed via the `lxde` package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Unity on Debian](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23953/installing-unity-on-debian)

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no Debian repository for Unity Desktop, at least an official one. As suggested above, have a look on [Installing Unity on Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23953/installing-unity-on-debian).

But why you are after unity ? There is many other desktop like `KDE`,`Gnome3`, `XFCE`, `LXQt` , `LXDE` etc. Try `KDE`, this one is awesome, with all bells and whistles, and easily customizable.

**Install It**

`sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop`

You will need a little patience, experiment with it and feel its awesomeness.